# Specify a different stylesheet for iframe on Facebook

Tags: css, facebook, iframe

I want to apply a specific stylesheet for the content of an external page (that I own) when it is shown in an iframe on Facebook. Due to the width limitations of Facebook, I'd like to display just one column from a page, without altering the HTML of that page. When visited directly, the page would call the regular CSS. When seen through the iframe, it would call a facebook-specific CSS.

In other words, how can one make Facebook use a specific CSS file when it shows content through the iframe? Do I have to use javascript to grab a different stylesheet?

Answer (score 2):

With PHP you can check wether your application is runnning inside the Facebook iframe or not. You have to check the `$_REQUEST` array and search for the parameters that FB passes to the iframe. They usually start with `fb_`, and they may vary depending on the settings that you have checked for your app.

Something like this should work:

```
<?php
    $fbFrame = false;

    foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $value)
    {
       if (strpos($key, "fb_") > -1)
       {
          $fbFrame = true;
          break;
       }
    }

    if (array_key_exists('signed_request', $_REQUEST)
        $fbFrame = true; 
?>
```

Then, in your HTML head:

```
<head>
<?php if ($fbFrame): ?>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="PATH_TO_FB_CSS" />
<?php else: ?>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="PATH_TO_NORMAL_CSS" />
<?php endif; ?>
</head>
```

I'm assuming that you don't have any parameter of your own starting with `fb_` or called `signed_request` into your `$_GET` or `$_POST`, of course.

Answer (score 2):

This is as easy as printing out different styles when you are running in iframe or not. True, if you run this site inside iframe at some other site, this will take affect as well. But realistically, facebook is the most important one, as long as that is running do you really care?

this is working for me. Hope it works for you as well.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
    <title>My Coolest Site</title>
    <link type="text/css" href="/css/my-common-1.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link type="text/css" href="/css/my-common-2.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    if (top === self) {
          document.write('<link type="text/css" href="/css/my-specific-1.css" rel="stylesheet">');
          document.write('<link type="text/css" href="/css/my-specific-2.css" rel="stylesheet">');

    } else { 
          document.write('<link type="text/css" href="/css/my-fb-1.css" rel="stylesheet">');
          document.write('<link type="text/css" href="/css/my-fb-2.css" rel="stylesheet">');
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Because it's in an Iframe, the **same origin policy** applies. You cannot access what comes from a different domain.